# Wordpress image description link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've modified this code that displays the description of an image:

```
function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
  global $post;
  $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
  $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

  if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
  echo '<p>'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_content.'</p>';
  }
}
```

What I need is on how to display the description of an image on a popup window once it was clicked. What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

The file goes like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="primary">
    <!--    <div id="content" role="main"> -->
        <!--</div><!-- #content -->
        <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/wordpress/?page_id=5'): ?>
            <!--<div style="float:right">-->
            <div style="width:640px; float:left;min-height:290px;word-wrap: break-word">
                <?php
                    $myposts = get_posts('');
                    foreach($myposts as $post) :
                        setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                <div class="post-item">
                    <div class="post-info">
                        <h2 class="post-title">
                            <!--<a href="<?php //the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php //the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php //the_title(); ?></a>-->
                            <b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
                        </h2>
                        <!--<p class="post-meta">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?></p>-->
                    </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <div style="margin:25px 0px;border:1px dotted #ccc; width: 640px;"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php //comments_template(); ?>
                <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width:319px; min-height:200px; border-left:1px solid #ccc">
                <div style="float:left; margin-left:5px">
                    <h2 style="font-family:Mybold; font-size:14pt">Categories</h2>
                    <?php
                    the_post_thumbnail_caption();
                    $categories = get_categories();
                    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                       $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
                       ?><p><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name"><?php if($cat->parent < 1) echo $cat->cat_name; //echo $cat->category_nicename; ?></a></p><?php ; 
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div><!-- #primary --> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the final html being produced for each paragraph containing the image please?

Comment: I just posted the file.

Comment: That's your raw PHP+HTML - I was really looking for the final HTML - i.e. what HTML looks like in the browser.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of how it looks like. http://tinypic.com/r/oqae78/6 so for instance I clicked the image, a popup window will appear displaying the description of an image.

Comment: Since you have A LOT duplicated questions like :Wordpress image description, Wordpress image post link Wordpress image description popup I recommend to DELETE THEM (since it piss people off as you already noticed...). Trust me I made the same error when starting at Stack Owerflow.All the best... – Dejo Dekic 2 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Very quick thought - take a look at https://github.com/mikezahno/jPicDetail - a jQuery plugin for overlaying text on images.
There is a jsFiddle demo link on that page too.

Comment: I'm new in wordpress. Thanks for the plugin. But how am I be able to show the description of an image that was clicked?

Comment: The point with this jQuery plugin is that you don't have to click - you just mouseover and the description is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin. But I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only way i can think how to solve this is : Add your image A TITLE and then you can do 
something like this:

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ek9zP/)

```
$('img').click(function(){
 var getTitle = $(this).attr('title');
 alert(getTitle);

 });
```

Of course you must include jquery into your page see [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) how to do this.